# NFC RFID in Web Application

Tags: javascript, php, nfc

How can I connect NFC in web application? Should i use a plugin or applet to read NFC in web apps using php or javascript.

I tried this one but it doesn't work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5XOr30fQJE

Comment: php is server side - a server reading NFC is like a chicken with a bicycle

Comment: Is it possible to do in javascript?

Comment: on a phone, right?

Comment: Both desktop browsers and phone.

Comment: desktop NFC reader? browsers do not have access to low level hardware and peripherals

Comment: Yes I'm using KKmoon nfc rfid

Comment: yeah ... browsers don't have access to such devices ... not on desktop nor in a phone

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side language. Data taken from NFC are sent to server and then could be processed by PHP but communication with NFC needs to be managed by another language, see https://w3c.github.io/web-nfc/ for more info